# find :all conditions for hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my database I have the table 'audits' which contains a field called 'changes' which stores data in the form of hash.

I would like to retrieve all audits with the following conditions:

```
- auditable_type = 'Expression'
- action = 'destroy'
- changes = :EXP_SUBMISSION_FK =>'9999992642' #note that this field stores hash values

@expression_history_deleted = Audit.find(:all, :conditions => ["auditable_type =? AND action = ? AND changes = ?",'Expression', 'destroy' , { :EXP_SUBMISSION_FK =>'9999992642'} ])
```

The code above return nothing.

If I remove 'changes' in the condition so that it reads as follows, I get a list of entries:

```
@expression_history_deleted = Audit.find(:all, :conditions => ["auditable_type =? AND action = ?",'Expression', 'destroy'])



   <% @expression_history_deleted.each do |test| %>
    <%= test.changes['EXP_SUBMISSION_FK'] %> ---displays the value
    <% end %>
```

My question is how do I perform a search and set the conditions for the hash value.

```
****
```

I am using 'acts_as_audited' which stores all the changes in hash format in the 'audits' table.

```
****
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using the serialize function in ActiveRecord?

Unfortunately, I don't think it's easily possible to search it on the SQL level. It's obviously possible to pull out all of the records and handle the search in Ruby, but that's less than ideal.

I'd recommend moving anything you need to search on out of the serialized column and into its own.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am using 'acts_as_audited' which stores all the changes in hash format in the 'audits' table.

Comment: In that case, I think I will need to retrieve the records and perform the search using ruby

Comment: That seems like the simplest solution. The other way is to do like Vladson suggested and try to get some complex full text searching going on, but since we're dealing with actual data and not just text, it'd make me paranoid.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ActiveRecord serialize macros, then you may dump containment of column `changes` and separete constructions like "audible_type: Expression". Try performing a series of fulltext search on that column and the work is done. 
But more preferable way is to extract that data into real database level colums